# Scale point layer around a point

Tags: qgis, qgis-3

I am trying to scale a point layer in QGIS 3.10 around a certain point A. Ideally, after the transformation each point should be x metres closer to A, x being a fixed value and not a variable. All points in my layer are further than x metres from A.

It would be an affine transformation for each point individually, but not for the whole layer. I feel like I'm overlooking some very simple solution, but can't figure out how to go about this and couldn't find any answers on this site. I am open to R solutions as well.

Comment: Is x metres a variable? you may make a buffer of that x and then intersect it with lines

Comment: what if a point is already closer than x metres to A? I have an outline solution which is to draw rays from A to each point P, then intersect the rays with an x metre buffer around each P, then take the nearest of the two intersection points. So can be done with spatial operations in QGIS but almost easier to program in Python or R with a more direct method.

Comment: If you wish to ask about how to do this using R (or Python) then please do so in a separate question and be sure to include a code attempt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start with a single "hub" point ("Centre", green) and some "spoke" points ("PPoints", mustard):

[image]

Run "Distance to nearest hub" with your points as the source and your centre point as the hub:

[image]

to get some lines to each point:

[image]

then do a buffer of your points of your desired length, and run "polygons to lines" so that your buffers are line features and not polygons. You can delete the polygon versions of your buffers:

[image]

Then "Line Intersections" will get you points that are the buffer size nearer to the source point (orange points here):

[image]

I'm not sure if you get an attribute relating back to the original point, there might be some other options in the dialogs to keep an ID of the source. But anyway, that generates the points!

Comment: That solved it for me - thank you!